# SQL query for until 2005 but not after 2005?

Tags: sql

Find all Id who had taught until 2005 but had not taught after 2005.

for eg.

```
year ID
2010 A
2009 C
2005 B
2002 D
2002 C
2001 B
2000 A
```

Then the result should give only B and D.

The table has columns ID and year and I want to print out ID.

```
SELECT ID
FROM university.teaches
WHERE year <= 2005 AND 
year NOT IN (SELECT year FROM university.teaches WHERE year> 2005);
```

I am trying something like this but it gives result including A and C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check for ids and not years with the IN operator:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID
FROM university.teaches
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM university.teaches WHERE year > 2005);
```

The subquery of `IN` returns all the ids that have taught after 2005, so `NOT IN` will return all the rest ids.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/w9eBZ369NtGuTZo493AGdd/0).
Results:

```
| ID  |
| --- |
| B   |
| D   |
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP BY` and `MAX()`:

```
select id
from university.teaches
group by id
having max(year) <= 2005;
```